# How can I detect if an Android device is indoor/outdoor?

Tags: android, location

I'm developing an app which fuses location from various providers, hoping it will give a more accurate location than if I simply used the Google API. However, the choice of providers would depend on the phone being indoor or outdoor (Network vs GPS, for example).

What is the best way to detect if the device is indoor or outdoor? My first thought would be using the Light sensor, and maybe cell signal strength and WiFi (if there are WiFi networks near, it's likely the device is indoor), but I don't know which weight/confidence I should attribute to these sensors.

**Edit:** this is for my masters thesis, in which the goal is to get the location from the different providers (GPS, Network and Passive) in the Android API, and fuse them with a formula. Depending on whether the phone is indoor or outdoor, the several locations would have different weights. There would also be parameters like if battery life is priority or not (I haven't developed this formula yet).

Comment: This sounds like a really difficult problem with lots of strange edgecases. If you can find a different way to make your app, I would do so.

Comment: If your WiFi hotspot has really good outdoor coverage or you're in an area that has municipal WiFi then that kind of rules out using WiFi to determine whether you are indoors or outdoors. If you're just going for additional location accuracy, nearly every modern Android (and Apple) device uses A-GPS, which already uses a combination of GPS, cellular, WiFi, and in some cases Bluetooth signals to improve location accuracy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

Comment: light? how about day/night, sunny/overcast, in the shadow/in my pocket ? starbucks/mcdonalds wifi is usually detected from at least across the street. network coverage can vary for a number of reason. GPS altitude could help if you are several floors above the ground.

Comment: @njzk2 GPS altitude shows altitude above WGS84 surface, not level of local ground

Comment: @Salauyou yes, of course it does. but you can do a subtraction, can't you?

Comment: @njzk2 if I live in a hilly town such manipulations won't help :)

Comment: you will geocode your position into an address, from which you will reverse geocode it into a ground position. anyway, the vertical precision in most GPS is quite low, so unless you leave in high rises, it won't really help.

Comment: @njzk2 it will work only if internet is accessible  and in very unpredictable way...

Comment: @Salauyou: detecting the notion of indoor/outdoor on a phone is quite unreliable already, so...

Comment: @njzk2 agree... I cannot imagine how it can be obtained. Small wooden house, for example, is absolutely the same as outdoor in terms of geomagnetic field and radio signal transmission...

Comment: This is really tricky. From my point of view it'll have to be a combination of various info like GPS (first), light + temperature + time (second), speed (third).

Comment: Did you find a way to calculate this?

Comment: @Oliver is here to tell you to just forget about it cause it's too difficult with that counter-industrious vibe.

Answer (score 4):

Just subscribe to both providers and use `location.getProvider()` and `location.getAccuracy()` when new location arrives--to check if it's more/less accurate then previous.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your best bet is the GPS signal itself, because GPS rarely penetrates buildings.

In built up areas, you'll encompass WiFi networks all over the shop.

Comment: GPS will sometimes penetrate a one story house quite easily.

Comment: But GPS is the best hint.